# How do we create spatial index on views if it is possible?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to create spatial index on sql server 2008? If yes how do we create it on table with schemabinding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe you can.  XML and Spatial Indexes can only be created tables.  Not views.

**Edit**:

Here's some proof for you straight from [BOL: Restrictions on Spatial Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964740.aspx)

> Spatial Indexes cannot be specified on indexed views.